# getUserTimeLine (Twitter4J) only works on some public accounts

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, twitter4j

I try to use *getUserTimeline()* from Twitter4J library to download **public tweets** and it only works on some accounts. For example:

```
twitter.getUserTimeline("twitter"); //works
twitter.getUserTimeline("codeacademy"); //fails
```

However, I can't find any difference between the two. I am followed by none of them nor do I follow any. If I visit their accounts in Firefox's private mode, I am able to see their public tweets. It is the same when I login with my account. However, if I try to use API, codeacademy somehow fails. I tried calling it with argument "codeacademy", "Codeacademy", even with ID (716547158), always with the same results.

Error message I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
{"request":"\/1.1\/statuses\/user_timeline.json?screen_name=codeacademy&include_my_retweet=true&include_entities=1&include_rts=1","error":"Not authorized."}

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=00df323f or
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=445fb8e5
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[00df323f-445fb8e5], statusCode=401, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=177, limit=180, resetTimeInSeconds=1384522960, secondsUntilReset=495}, version=3.0.4}   
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:162)  
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)     
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:81)
    ...etc...
```

I've thought I may be initializing Twitter object wrong, but trying 3 different options didn't help. Here is what I've tried.

## 1)

in twitter4j.properties (*** are actual values there :))

```
oauth.consumerKey=***
oauth.consumerSecret=***
oauth.accessToken=***
oauth.accessTokenSecret=***
```

in java

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
```

## 2)

in twitter4j.properties

```
enableApplicationOnlyAuth=true
http.useSSL=true
oauth.consumerKey=***
oauth.consumerSecret=***
oauth2.tokenType=bearer
oauth2.accessToken=***
```

I got oauth2 values by calling and manually copy-pasting from:

```
    OAuth2Token token = twitter.getOAuth2Token();
    System.out.println(token.getAccessToken());
    System.out.println(token.getTokenType());
```

in java

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getSingleton();
```

## 3)

in twitter4j.properties

```
*nothing*
```

in java

```
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setUseSSL(true);
    builder.setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true);

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("***", "***");
    OAuth2Token token = twitter.getOAuth2Token();
```

Every attempt worked with twitter, none worked with codeacademy.

I must be doing something wrong but am not able to find out what. Any advice would be highly appreciated :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go here: https://twitter.com/codeacademy

Its written on the page itself , that the tweets of this user are protected, only the followers have the access to the tweets of this account.

Hence, you can get the tweets:

- If the authentication credentials of [codeacademy](https://twitter.com/codeacademy) are used.
- Or, the authentication credentials of the user following [codeacademy](https://twitter.com/codeacademy) are used.

Comment: Thanks, the real problem was between the monitor and chair - I didn't notice it is CodeCademy, not CodeAcademy. Too bad I've spent so much time on this :-/.

Comment: @Samuel happens to me all the time, after all the r&d, i realize that the only mistake i made was , the case difference in the name of the variable.